# How to get version of SharePoint 2013 installed?

Tags: 2013, installation

How I can get the version of SharePoint that is installed on my server?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Run this PowerShell script

```
get-spfarm | select BuildVersion
```

Answer (score 5):

```
PS C:\> (Get-SPFarm).Products
```

> ```
> GUID                                 Product
> 35466B1A-B17B-4DFB-A703-F74E2A1F5F5E Project Server 2013 
> BC7BAF08-4D97-462C-8411-341052402E71 Project Server 2013 Preview 
> C5D855EE-F32B-4A1C-97A8-F0A28CE02F9C SharePoint Server 2013 
> CBF97833-C73A-4BAF-9ED3-D47B3CFF51BE SharePoint Server 2013 Preview 
> B7D84C2B-0754-49E4-B7BE-7EE321DCE0A9 SharePoint Server 2013 Enterprise 
> 298A586A-E3C1-42F0-AFE0-4BCFDC2E7CD0 SharePoint Server 2013 Enterprise Preview 
> D6B57A0D-AE69-4A3E-B031-1F993EE52EDC Microsoft Office Web Apps Server 2013 
> 9FF54EBC-8C12-47D7-854F-3865D4BE8118 SharePoint Foundation 2013
> ```

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/ec20dbf5-03e8-482d-88b9-f1624e93c9b6/sharepoint-version?forum=sharepointadmin

http://blogs.technet.com/b/steve_chen/archive/2013/03/26/3561010.aspx

or manual:

central admin -> upgrade and migration -> check product and patch installation status

you should see a list of patches youve done (service packs/hot fix) , product type like Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013 and its versiom number, numbers can be found here to cross check:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/steve_chen/archive/2013/03/26/3561010.aspx

Answer (score 4):

### Server Side Object Model

Another option to determine SharePoint version via PowerShell:

```
(Get-PSSnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell).Version
```

For example, the command:

```
(Get-PSSnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell).Version.Major
```

returns `15` if SharePoint 2013 is installed

---

### Client Side Object Model

How to determine SharePoint version via CSOM (ECMAScript):

```
function getSPServerVersion(result) {
    clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function(){
           var serverVersion = clientContext.get_serverVersion();
           result(serverVersion);
        }, 
        function(){
           result(null); 
        });
}



//Usage
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function(){
    getSPServerVersion(function(serverVersion)
    {
        console.log("SharePoint instance version:" + serverVersion);
    });
});
```

References:

- [SP.ClientContext.serverVersion property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/jj247006.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use SharePoint Central administration Site:

Central Administration--> System Settings --> Manage servers in this farm